# reference cursor fetches to rows with different columns

Tags: oracle, cursor

I have problems with fetching a reference cursor.

Let's say I have variable of reference cursor, of "c_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR", and the reference cursor would have rows with columns as following

columnA | columnB | columnC
   test           123            abc

And I have this row type variable "r_table TestTable%rowtype"
This row type has columnA, columnB and column C with extra columns. so it would be like this
columnA | columnB | columnC | columnD | columnE | columnF

So what I want to do is to create a row with the columnA, B and C fetched from the cursor values and the rest columns given some hard coded values

```
loop
   fetch c_cursor into r_table -- but with extra value hard coded
end loop;
```

So the final result that I expect is 
  columnA | columnB | columnC | columnD | columnE | columnF  
   test           123            abc            some         coded         vlues

the columnA,B and C are the same in reference cursor and rowtype.
Should I create some kind of temporal variable to save the values from the reference cursor and then pass the values into the final row?? I think it is not that efficient

Can you guys give me some good ideas of doing this??

thanks

Comment: do it in straight SQL join and forget the cursors

Comment: I should use the cursor...any idea??

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE testTable ( A, B, C, D, E ) AS
  SELECT 'A', 1, DATE '2017-01-01', 123.2, 'DEF' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', 2, DATE '2017-01-02', 456.5, 'GHI' FROM DUAL;
```

**PL/SQL**:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  TYPE abc_type IS RECORD(
    A testTable.A%TYPE,
    B testTable.B%TYPE,
    C testTable.C%TYPE
  );

  CURSOR c_cursor IS
    SELECT A, B, C FROM testTable;

  r_table TestTable%ROWTYPE;
  abc     ABC_TYPE;
BEGIN
  OPEN c_cursor;
  LOOP
    FETCH c_cursor INTO abc;
    EXIT WHEN c_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    r_table.A := abc.A;
    r_table.B := abc.B;
    r_table.C := abc.C;
    r_table.D := 789.7; -- Some hard-coded value
    r_table.E := 'JKL'; -- Some hard-coded value
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
      r_table.A||','||r_table.B||','||r_table.C||','||r_table.D||','||r_table.E
    );
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE c_cursor;
END;
/
```